# IndexOutOfRangeException bug in NameValueCollection.Add()?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a strange case where once in a while, an instance of NameValueCollection will crash my application when I am trying to add data to it, or iterate over it.  This is a MVC5 application that I host on IIS and the code in question is called from a Razor view page (.cshtml).  Here is the code + stack trace:

```
// 'slides' is a static list of image related data.
if (slides != null && slides.Count >= 1)
{
    // Splat!  Sometimes this crashes...
    Model.CustomMetadata.Add("og:image", slides[0].Path);
}
```

**Message:**
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

**Stack Trace:**
at System.Collections.ArrayList.Add(Object value)
at System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.Add(String name, String value)

Here is another place in the code where I also get weird, and intermittent behaviour:

```
@foreach (var m in Model.CustomMetadata.AllKeys)
{
    // This also seems strange since I am iterating over the keys, but getting IndexOutOfRangeException...
    <meta property="@m" content="@Model.CustomMetadata[m]" />
}
```

When this problem occurs (intermittently, after a daily reboot of the IIS server), I resolve it by manually restarting the application in IIS.  After that, everything works fine until the next reboot kills it.

Has anyone experienced this before, or might know what could be the culprit?

Comment: Where does `slides` coming from?

Comment: @haim770 'slides' is just an instance of a POCO that contains data about an image.  As you can see, I ensure that it is non-null and contains data (and it does).

Comment: This is multi-thread scenario? show some more code especially where the slides defined

Comment: Does `slides[0].Path` have a value?

Comment: @DetectivePikachu, Yes, it does.

Comment: @Serghei  Yes, since this is an ASP.NET application, it is a multithread scenario.  However, 'slides' is a static list, which obviously has content given the code.

Comment: @A.R. that is could cause the problem in multi-threading scenario when you have static state and 2 simultaneous threads one read other one change try to avoid global statics in that case

Comment: @Serghei 'slides' is populated in a static constructor, and never modified.  The error in question is also happening on Model.CustomMetadata, which is not static.

Answer (score 0):

You have thread safety problem.

`NameValueCollection` is [not thread safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8#thread-safety). [Under the hood it uses ArrayList](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/namevaluecollection.cs,277) which is dynamically resized.
It is possible that you have hit the `.Add()` method exactly when resizing was happening. Same thing will happen when accessing `.AllKeys`.

---

**This is not very hard to happen:**
One request to the server was trying to add something to the collection and another request was trying to resize the collection.

As alternative you can use something like [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) or more appropriate collection from [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8) namespace.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that is the issue.  This collection is created per-request and this is the only place where its members are accessed.  Nothing is ever removed from the collection, only added, and then iterated over.

Comment: Adding still requires resizing.

Comment: @A.R. Above, you said, "'slides' is a static list". If you meant `slides` is defined as `private static NameValueCollection slides` in your class, then thread safety is definitely the problem.

Comment: @howcheng Model.CustomMetadata is the NameValueCollection (constructed each request) that is causing the exception, slides is a static list of POCO types.  And by static, I mean unchanging for the life of the application.  It is never modified.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu That may be, but the member that is throwing the exception is not being accessed from multiple threads.

Comment: @A.R. I agree with you. If the collection is created per request and there are no Tasks, Threads modifying the collection concurrently, then there is something else to it. Is it possible that the initial value of the collection is some shared static variable, like Model.CustomMetadata = globalState ?

Comment: @vasiloreshenski No, the collection is a normal auto property with an initializer, so no intermediate shared state.  Further, when I get the error, it happens for EVERY request until I restart the app.  My past experience with race conditions is that they happen randomly, rather than uniformly...

Comment: @A.R. Yeah, they are random. Some will pass and other will fail. I will try to simulate it tomorrow. In the mean time you can try catch the exception (then rethrow it) to log the Length, Count values of the collection to see what is the actual size. I am thinking for some int overflow, but hardly the case.

Comment: @vasiloreshenski That is a good idea.  All I have to do is wait for the problem to pop up again, :)